# cannot import name 'ripser' from 'persim' nor persim.plot

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to import the following two lines:

```
from persim import ripser
from persim.plot import plot_persistence_diagram
```

However, I am told that "cannot import name 'ripser' from 'persim'" and "No module named 'persim.plot'". How can I solve this?

I tried updating persim multiple times and internet searching, but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: According to the [homepage](https://pypi.org/project/ripser/), ripser is its own package.  It is not part of persim.  Why are you trying to import it as part of persim?

Comment: You should read the documentation before "searching the internet" for a solution.  It is more productive.  Try this for example: https://persim.scikit-tda.org/en/latest/notebooks/Persistence%20images.html

Comment: Note: There is apparently no such thing as persim.plot.  The "plot_persistence_diagram" appears to be a gudhi method or function.